# For the half reaction HSO3- -> S2O6^2- why is it that 2e- are on the right hand side when balancing and not one electron?

Tags: homework, inorganic-chemistry, redox

$$\ce{HSO3- -> S2O6^2-}$$

The oxidation number of $\ce{S}$ on the left is +4 and +5 so when adding electrons to balance the oxidation number why is $\ce{2e-}$ added to the right instead of one? 
Why is 2 placed in front of the $\ce{HSO3-}$?

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Comment: Also, HSO3 has a negative charge on it.

Comment: No it's not a homework question. I'm finished school and I am revising. I know that the balanced equation is 2HSO3-  --> S2O62-  + 2H+ + 2e- . I'm just confused about why there are 2 electrons instead of one when you balance it.

Comment: A "homework question" is any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself. This includes not just questions from actual homework assignments, but also self-study problems, puzzles, etc.

Comment: @Jasper. What are the requirements for a balanced equation?

Comment: well usually when I'm balancing redox reactions, I find the oxidation numbers of the atoms and then balance the oxidation numbers using electrons. Then I balance the charges using H+ or OH- depending on whether its an acidic or basic reaction and balance o and h atoms using H2O if needed. I'm sure it's something simple but I don't understand why there are 2e- instead of just one on the right.

Comment: there's two s's on the right so you need two s's on the left so you balance it by adding 2 in front of HSO3-  so is that why you multiply the oxidation numbers by 2 so it becomes +8 on the left and +10 on the right?

Comment: @Jan oh woops i see that now just below where I'm typing. I don't really get the logic of multiplying the oxidation numbers by 2 as i thought the coefficient had no effect on the oxidation number?

Comment: @Jan thanks! I always over think these type of things :P

Answer (score 2):

> Why is $2$ placed in front of the $\ce{HSO3}$?

This is, of course, the elemental law of the conservation of mass. You have $x$ atoms that you put into your equation, you need to get $x$ atoms out again. While hydrogen and oxygen can be taken care of with water, you need to account for the sulphur immediately. Hence you need two sulphurs.

> The oxidation number of S on the left is +IV and +V so when adding electrons to balance the oxidation number why is $\ce{2e-}$ added to the right instead of one?

The oxidation numbers are, of course, correct, but remember that in the first step you wrote a $2$ before the sulphur. Therefore you now have *two sulphurs* that you need to treat with the appropriate number of electrons — either by stealing or by gifting.

Since you have two sulphurs and they each lose one electron, you need to add $\ce{2 e-}$ to the right.

---

Note: The OP already understood what went wrong through hints in the comments. Unfortunately, OP decided not to write up a self-answer.